# Placing a Laplacian Pyramid Image onto a black canvas changes the background

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing

I've built a function that takes an image, and builds a Laplacian Pyramid from it. I want to take, say, the first image of the Laplacian Pyramid and place it onto a black canvas(using np.zeros to build it).

I've done this, but what I get is that the black canvas takes on a color similar to the Laplacian Image, instead of remaining black.[image]

The code basically replaces an NxM spot on the canvas with the laplacian image:

canvas[0:768, 0:1024] = laplace_image

I was wondering what exactly I'm missing here, as trying this with a grayscale image yields the correct canvas.

[image]

And the plotting code which is probably the issue:

```
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(canvas, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Here is an example of the values in a Laplacian Image

```
[[0.00206756 0.00217308 0.00229568 0.00241833 0.00253975 0.0026407
  0.0027411  0.00283026 0.00289416 0.00295967 0.00302006 0.003061
  0.00308811 0.00310638 0.00311357 0.00311655 0.00312005 0.00312285
  0.00311985 0.00311802 0.003109   0.00308746 0.00304459 0.00298541
  0.00291537 0.00283966 0.00276133 0.00267244 0.00255839 0.00242822
  0.002288   0.002139  ]

 [0.00066538 0.00070738 0.00075546 0.00080446 0.00084945 0.00087207
  0.00088813 0.00091252 0.0009471  0.00099087 0.00103915 0.00107427
  0.00109442 0.00109901 0.00110466 0.00110936 0.0011094  0.0011042
  0.0010959  0.00109445 0.00109941 0.00108648 0.00105162 0.00103264
  0.00101328 0.00098499 0.00094468 0.00089966 0.00084997 0.00079252
  0.00072701 0.00066181]]
```

Comment: Can you post your actual plotting code? Like, the functions you call to make the plot and such

Comment: @tel Added it, thanks

Comment: hmm, you're already using `cmap='gray'`, so that's the obvious issue already taken care of. Can you add an example of what the data in the array `canvas` looks like? What's the shape of `canvas`?

Comment: Canvas is just an np matrix filled with zeros using np.zeroes, according to the dimensions of the 4-5 images I need to place in it. If I were to replace the images with grayscale images, everything works fine and the background is black

Comment: The colors that get chosen can depend on the exact shape and contents of `canvas` immediately before you call `imshow`. It'll help if you're more specific. In particular, can you add an example to the question that shows the range of the data in the arrays that represent your laplacian images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `vmin=0` will ensure that all zeros in `canvas` get interpreted as black by `imshow`:

```
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(canvas, cmap='gray', vmin=0)
plt.show()
```

Before it's fed into your colormap, the data in `canvas` is first normalized so that the smallest value corresponds to black and the largest value corresponds to white. You can control the normalization by passing in the `vmin` and `vmax` arguments to `imshow`. For `cmap=gray`, any values `x <= vmin` will get displayed as black, and any values `x >= vmax` will get displayed as white.

You reproduce a similar problem to the one you describe if there's any negative values in the image data:

```
img = np.zeros((500,1000))
img[:, :250] = -2
img[:, 250:500] = 2
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
```

[image]

Passing in `vmin=0` will cause the zeros in the second half of `img` to be displayed as black instead of gray:

```
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray', vmin=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution tel! I normalized the values of the image instead of changing any paramters in imshow and now it's outputting correctly!